# Django, AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hope everyone is doing well.

I'm trying to deploy a Django APP to elastic beanstalk however it is failing.

The error is `Following services are not running: web`

I'm not sure how to resolve it, I changed settings to be `allowed_hosts = ['*']` but this still came up with the error.

I'm concerned it may be the database connection?

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': '***',
        'USER': '***',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'HOST': '***.***.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated I've googled and googled and tried and tried but no solutions have worked for me (works fine with manage.py runserver).

The logs have not been much help to me as I don't understand them that well.

When I attempt to connect I get this in the nginx logs.

`4335#4335: *88 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream`

The daemon.log have these warnings:

`WARN -- : log file "/var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.2022-06-20-01" does not exist`

The engine.log has these warnings:

```
[WARN] Warning: process healthd is already registered...
Deregistering the process ...
[WARN] stopProcess Warning: process xray is not registered 
[WARN] deregisterProcess Warning: process httpd is not registered, skipping...
```

(Note: This is my first time using AWS EB)

Comment: did you set your inbound rules properly?

Comment: I set inbound rules but not sure if properly. I basically set up all to see if that was the issue.

`IPv6, All Traffic,  All Protocol, All Port, Source: 0.0.0.0/0`

`IPv4, All Traffic,  All Protocol, All Port, Source: ::/0`

Comment: Check this video [https://youtu.be/6diwIYhnCQg](https://youtu.be/6diwIYhnCQg)

Comment: @ahmedshahriar Hi Ahmed, the app works fine in local, it actually calls the data from AWS RDS already, I just can't get the app to work on EB. 

I'm seriously stumped.

I might try load a blank django app and see if that works for me.

Comment: I did a blank project and loaded fine, so clearly I'm not following the process incorrectly it must be something wrong with my project. Would anyone know how I figure that out? works fine in local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue turned out to be with the django.config file.

originally I had web_project/wsgi.py.

I literally just updated per the django AWS tut and now it works, so much headache for such a simple thing.

[image]